# Can I slow down this Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jquery, so please forgive my ignorance. I created a webpage where you rollover a text link and an image in another div changes. I used the method from here: http://jsfiddle.net/fWpJz/1/ to create my page and it works well.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.productmenu a').hover(function () {
        $('#prodimage img').attr('src', $(this).data('image-src'));
        $('.image-src').stop().animate({.attr}, slow);
    });
});
```

I'd like to slow down the transition from one image to another on mouse over, so that the image doesn't flip as abruptly.

I used this tutorial (http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/) to create an effect that I like, but don't know how to combine it with the image changes based on a link hover. Here is the code from the jsfiddle.net:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu a').hover(function () {
        $('#container img').attr('src', $(this).data('image-src'));
    });
});
```

Can anyone point me to the correct piece of code and how I can add it into my javascript? I've never used jquery before, so I don't know how to add an animate function.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

What if I told you you didn't have to use jQuery.animate at all to achieve the effect you want? Use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)! Here's a [forked version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTm55/1/) showing how to accomplish what you're looking to do (I think) *(I've put the html/css/js at the bottom of this post as well)*.

When the DOM content has loaded, the `alignItems` function makes sure that all images stay in the same place on the page. The script keeps track of the current image being displayed. Every time a different link is moused over, the image being displayed gets updated, such that the old current image gets its opacity set to 0 and the new current image gets its opacity set to 1. Then CSS transitions can be used to animate the opacity, which blows away `$.fn.animate`, but will only work on modern browsers (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20transition)...motherf***ing IE -*_*- ). Code below:

**html**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" data-image-id="1">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-id="2">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-id="3">link 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-id="4">link 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-id="5">link 5</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <img id="1" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6330704947_dd7e1b453c_t.jpg" />
  <img id="2" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/13/15463218_8651d51b21_t.jpg"/>
  <img id="3" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2570/4220856234_029e5b8348_t.jpg" />
  <img id="4" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3036/2975303180_86c4858b2b_t.jpg" />
  <img id="5" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6216/6240217938_aeed84634a_t.jpg" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
.menu a {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  background: #333;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#container img {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alignImages();

  var currentImgId = 0;
  $('.menu a').hover(function () {
      var oldImgId = currentImgId;
      currentImgId = this.dataset.imageId;
      $(document.getElementById(oldImgId)).css('opacity', 0);
      $(document.getElementById(currentImgId)).css('opacity', 1.0);
  });
});

function alignImages() {
  var $images = $('#container img');
  var position = $images.eq(0).position();
  $images.each(function() {
    this.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.left = position.left;
    this.top = position.top;
  });
}
```

Comment: Note that this method will gracefully degrade for older browsers, there just won't be any animations. If animations are *absolutely necessary*, you could always fall back to jQuery's animate function.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(document.getElementById(oldImgId))` instead of `$('#' + oldImgId)`?

Comment: I always pass in DOM elements to jQuery whenever I can. It bypasses having to use jQuery's Sizzle engine, which can be a huge performance crutch. Although Sizzle is smart enough to to bypass having to do a full parse of a selector string when it's a simple ID, there's no reason to initialize the engine at all when you're doing something this simple, and especially when it could be happening as rapidly as a user mousing over different elements. In fact, I would've liked to rewrite *all* of this code in plain vanilla JS but didn't want to deviate too much from the original question.

Comment: Tangentially, this is one of my biggest pet peeves as a front-end developer; that people straight up *abuse* jQuery. It is an awesome library and is extremely powerful, but I find that a lot of people use it as an excuse not to have to learn vanilla DOM. This made sense back in the day when you had to deal with IE <9, and still makes sense if you need to support those browsers. But those days are coming to a close, and if all you're using jQuery for is to do some fancy animation and toggle classes on elements, you're wasting space over the wire and cycles on the client's browser.

Comment: "It bypasses having to use jQuery's Sizzle engine, yielding better performance" would have been plenty, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

your HTML should be like this:

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;">
  <img src="">
</div>
```

and in your script :

```
$('.menu a').hover(function () {
        $('#container').hide();

        $('#container').fadeIn().animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');

        $('#container img').attr('src', $(this).data('image-src'));
    });
```

Effect should be nice in transition See: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQQ3q/)**

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the implementations by using setTimeout

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu a').hover(function () {
        var self = this;
        var innerCount = ++count;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(innerCount == count) //If mouse move out within 1 second, will not show new image
            {
                $('#container img').attr('src', $(self).data('image-src'));
            }
        }, 1000); //1 second delay
    });
});
```